# UILocalNotification fires multiple times

Tags: uilocalnotification

An alarm application:
In my app,I set two alarms, the alarms have the same time and name, and add them to the local notifications ,when I click the iPhone's home button, the log print two notifications, but ,when the fire time is arriving, the dialog appears three times .
Is this the known bug of apple?
can everyone help me?